# prometheus cannot able to monitor all the pods in kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

So i have 3 name spaces when i deployed prometheus on kubernetes i see the error in the logs. it is unable to monitor all the name spaces.

Error :

```
\"system:serviceaccount:development:default\" cannot list endpoints at the cluster scope"
level=error ts=2018-06-28T21:22:07.390161824Z caller=main.go:216 component=k8s_client_runtime err="github.com/prometheus/prometheus/discovery/kubernetes/kubernetes.go:268: Failed to list *v1.Endpoints: endpoints is forbidden: User \"system:serviceaccount:devops:default\" cannot list endpoints at the cluster scope"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd better use a service account to access the kubernetes, and give the sa special privilidge that the prometheus needed. like the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: prometheus

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: prometheus
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - nodes
  - services
  - endpoints
  - pods
  verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources:
  - configmaps
  verbs: ["get"]
- nonResourceURLs: ["/metrics"]
  verbs: ["get"]

---

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: prometheus
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: prometheus
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: prometheus
  namespace: kube-system
```

Presumes that you deploy prometheus in the kube-system namespace. Also you need specify the sa like '   serviceAccount: prometheus' in your prometheus deployment file .

Comment: So i have 4 name spaces, 

kube-system,
devlopment,
default, and
test

how does it work for all name spaces ?

Should i just mention .

subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: prometheus
  namespace: kube-system <- ( just kube-system would be enough ? to monitor all the pods in other name spaces ? )

Comment: Service account created in one namespace can monitor all the pods in all namespaces, that's the privilidge the ClusterRole prometheus gives.